# EF6 : Excluding one of the related tables when selecting

Tags: entity-framework-6, relational-database, relationship, data-retrieval

I've got a **MainTable** related as one-to-many with two tables **RelatedOne** and **RelatedTwo**.

I want to fetch a single row from the **MainTable** which includes **RelatedOne** only. So I want to exclude **RelatedTwo**.

I searched and tried a few solutions but I couldn't make it.

How can I handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried something like context.MainTable.Include(m => m.RelatedOne).Single(m => m.Id == myId); ?

Comment: Yes, i had tried that before I wrote here. The other one was still exist in the return value